# What does HapiFhir toListOfResourcesOfType() method do?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I have this getPatients() method where I get the patients whose family's names matches "Goodwin32". This is my code:

```
public List<Patient> getPatients(){
        Bundle bundle = client.search().forResource(Patient.class)
                .where(new StringClientParam("family").matches().value("Goodwin32"))
                .prettyPrint()
                .returnBundle(Bundle.class)
                .execute();
```

I try to extract the info from the bundle into a list by calling toListOfResourcesOfType() like this:-

```
 return BundleUtil.toListOfResourcesOfType(ctx, bundle, Patient.class);
```

However, the items returned are still a bundle and not a list of patients?

Answer (score 0):

That method should work exactly like you are expecting it to.

Do you mean you get a list of Bundles back from the toListOfResourcesOfType method? Are you sure that the server you are talking to is actually responding with the expected search results?